# is it better to use more blade or just enough blade?

Tags: power-tools, saw-blade, blade

Super novice question!

The blade speed at the points is the same regardless. Only the angle of attack changes. What are the pros and cons? I'd like to minimize chip out most of all since I'm working with very crappy material (plywood and melamine-faced chipboard).

[image: blade depth]

I am also interested if it's the same for other power saws.

Comment: The safest is with the minimum exposed blade.

Comment: *"I'd like to minimize chip out most of all"* On one or both faces? Crosscutting or ripping or both? What type of blade is fitted? (Most saws come with a combination blade, usually not a great one, and they tend to cut fast but leave ragged sawn faces and torn edges.) Last but not least, "very crappy material" doesn't really tell us enough, could you specify?

Comment: plywood and chipboard with melamine
no idea about my blade. i will have to check later today

Comment: @Wes on plywood and chipboard, I use a Diablo plywood blade. It works really nice.

Comment: The angle of attack is not the only thing that changes.  The amount of time each tooth is contacting the wood also changes.  Exposing just the minimum amount of blade to cut through can contribute to burning and is not as efficient due to the gullets clogging and increased friction.  I've heard recommendations to expose either a whole tooth or the whole gullet.

Comment: Ref that discusses some of these comments: https://www.thisoldhouse.com/how-to/circular-saw-101-how-to-adjust-blade-depth

Comment: 2 things. Remember that one side chips out more than the other side, and cut accordingly. Wrapping your cut line (both sides) in masking tape will often help a lot with chipout.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the recommended height of the blade on a table saw while operating?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/what-is-the-recommended-height-of-the-blade-on-a-table-saw-while-operating)